# Why does WinForms fail to paint on occasion?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm responsible for supporting a winforms application, and occasionally, the app will not paint correctly. Sometimes numeric updowns will just be grey(the default control color), yet they'll still work. Other times certain buttons won't paint correctly.

We haven't written any custom painting code, no GDI+, nada. Therefore, AFAIK, everything should be handled by Windows.

The trouble is, tickets will come in with photos of parts of the app that haven't rendered properly, and I don't know how to even begin debugging them, because I have no idea what might be wrong.

So, the question is, why does WinForms fail to paint sometimes? Are there certain things I should be looking towards?

Comment: WinForms rarely fails to pain.

Answer (score 4):

In Winforms the UI and the logic are normally executed on the SAME thread.

So when you block the UI thread by querying a database, reading a file or whatever takes more time than can go unnoticed the UI will not be updated for that time.

Another reason can be that the thread simply doesn't get time to execute because an other thread has a higher priority and gets time on the CPU.

Comment: This would make sense in the short run, but sometimes these problems persist on the order of tens of minutes.

Comment: @Jonathan Beerhalter, Still, what I put in my answer is how it (should) work. There is always a reason why the UI isn't being updated and the reasons I gave are the official ones. All others are bugs and are hard for me to list.

Comment: But what you said doesn't work, because the UI thread isn't locked up, and it never paints certain portions of the UI. I was hoping for some reasons why that would happen, not UI development tips 101.

Comment: @Jonathan Beerhalter, Indeed, perhaps the UI thread isn't doing anything but how do you know it isn't locked up by other threads having a higher priority?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Erno has said, I would add that I had some weird issues when one of the winforms apps I was working on used a transparency color for some images that was common in my controls.  If your app is using any images and you've set a transparency color that your buttons or controls are using, weird things happen.